# How to activate modal from controlller passing data to view. (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, controller, bootstrap-modal, pass-data

Suppose I have a login form and a bootstrap modal inside it and after checking login authentication from a controller, I want to pass data to that bootstrap modal.
So how can I activate that modal from controller passing data to that modal?

Comment: Please show/add some of your code.

Comment: This is possible, read carefully this part of the Bootstrap 4 modal explanation : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.
I passed the data from controller like this

```
return view('welcome', ['getData'=>$getData]);
```

and then i checked condition if there is present data then i showed the modal.

```
@if(isset($getData))
<script>
    $('#resultModal').modal('show')
</script>
```

@endif